# Password Reset - passing object to .NET Core API

Tags: angular, .net-core

I'm coming up against an issue (I'm learning C# and Angular) where when trying to data to my API its coming up with and error that I'm unable to solve.

When a user requests a forgot password email they are emailed a link which contains their email and a token generated by Microsoft Identity.  When clicking that link they are brought to a page that allows them to enter a new password and confirm it, and that data is sent back to the API to change the password.

The issue I'm up against is something I'm not really sure on how to get around due to my lack of experience.  The error being thrown is:

zone.js:3372 POST http://localhost:5000/api/auth/ResetPasswordundefinedemail@domain.com 404 (Not Found)

If I send this up using Postman entering the details into the body of the post as JSON data, it functions fine and the password is successfully changed.  But when submitted through the Angular app, it goes wrong and I'm pretty sure its due to the formatting of the data being sent by the Angular App to the API.

In the Angular module where the user enters their new password, it submits the users email and token, as well as the password data to the API.  What I need to figure out is how to get the email and token into the model object that contains the new password.  The files are as follows:

change-password.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../../_services/auth.service';
import { AlertifyService } from '../../_services/alertify.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-email-change-password',
  templateUrl: './email-change-password.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./email-change-password.component.css']
})
export class EmailChangePasswordComponent {
  model: any;
  email: string;
  token: string;

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private authService: AuthService, private alertify: AlertifyService, private router: Router) {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.email = params['email'];
      this.token = params['token'];
      // console.log(this.email);
      // console.log(this.token);
    });
  }

  resetChangePassword() {
    this.authService.resetChangePassword(this.email, this.token, this.model).subscribe(next => {
    }, error => {
      this.alertify.error(error);
    }, () => {
      this.router.navigate(['/passwordchanged']);
    });
  }
}
```

From this file, the model contains the user submitted password and confirmed password.  It also grabs the email and token from thee URL params.  It is then sent to the API via the auth service.

auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { Clients } from '../_models/clients';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  //  Add a variable for out login url
  baseUrl = environment.apiUrl + 'auth/';
  jwtHelper = new JwtHelperService();
  decodedToken: any;

  // inject the HttpClient module and service into the constructor
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  // Add a new login method that will take the model object of type any form the login component and pass the
  // credentials to the API to be authenticated
  login(model: any) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'login', model)
      // A token is returned in the response from the server. Use RXJS operators by passing them through a pipe.
      // Transform the response with the map operator and store it locally (this is the token being stored in local storage)
      .pipe(
        map((response: any) => {
          const user = response;
          if (user) {
            localStorage.setItem('token', user.token);
            this.decodedToken = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(user.token);
          }
        })
      );
  }

  //  Register a new client user
  register(client: Clients) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'register', client);
  }

  // check if a user is logged into the portal or not.
  loggedIn() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    return !this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token);
  }

  // Send forgot password email
  resetpassword(model: any) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'forgotpassword', model);
  }

  // Change a users forgotten password
  resetChangePassword(email: string, token: string, model: any) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'ResetPassword' + model + email, token);
  }
}
```

AuthController.cs (I have removed the unrelated content from this)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Outmatch.API.Data;
using Outmatch.API.Dtos;
using Outmatch.API.Models;

namespace Outmatch.API.Controllers
{
    // Route will be api/auth (http://localhost:5000/api/auth)
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AuthController : ControllerBase
    {
        // Inject the auth repository and the programs configuration into the controller.
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        private readonly SignInManager<User> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
        private readonly IClientRepository _repo;
        private readonly IMailRepository _MailRepository;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly IResetPasswordRepository _resetPasswordRepository;
        public AuthController(IConfiguration config, IMapper mapper, UserManager<User> userManager, SignInManager<User> signInManager, 
            IClientRepository repo, IMailRepository MailRepository, IConfiguration configuration, IResetPasswordRepository resetPasswordRepository)
        {
            _resetPasswordRepository = resetPasswordRepository;
            _configuration = configuration;
            _MailRepository = MailRepository;
            _repo = repo;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _mapper = mapper;
            _config = config;
        }

        [HttpPost("ResetPassword")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ResetPassword(PasswordResetDto passwordResetDto)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = await _resetPasswordRepository.ResetPasswordAsync(passwordResetDto);

                if (result != null)
                    return Ok(result);

                return BadRequest(result);
            }

            return BadRequest("Invalid details");
        }
    }
}
```

IResetPasswordRepository:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Outmatch.API.Dtos;
using Outmatch.API.Models;

namespace Outmatch.API.Data
{
    public interface IResetPasswordRepository
    {
        Task<User> ResetPasswordAsync(PasswordResetDto passwordResetDto);
    }
}
```

ResetPasswordRepository:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities;
using Outmatch.API.Dtos;
using Outmatch.API.Models;

namespace Outmatch.API.Data
{
    public class ResetPasswordRepository : IResetPasswordRepository
    {
        private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
        public ResetPasswordRepository(UserManager<User> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }
        public async Task<User> ResetPasswordAsync(PasswordResetDto passwordResetDto)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(passwordResetDto.Email);
            if (user == null)
                return null;

            var decodedToken = WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(passwordResetDto.Token);
            string normalToken = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decodedToken);

            if (passwordResetDto.NewPassword != passwordResetDto.ConfirmPassword)
                return null;

            var result = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, normalToken, passwordResetDto.NewPassword);

            if (result.Succeeded)
                return null;

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

PasswordResetDto:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Outmatch.API.Dtos
{
    public class PasswordResetDto
    {
        [Required]
        public string Token { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 5)]
        public string NewPassword { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 5)]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm aware this is due to the API URL being incorrect, but I'm not sure how to get it formatted correctly so the users email, token, password and confirmedPassword are sent correctly to the API.

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is the url used in the postman

Comment: http://localhost:5000/api/auth/resetpassword is what is used, works fine.

Comment: `this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'ResetPassword' + model + email, token);` here your trying to string concat this will result localhost/restpassword/modelemailtoken

Comment: Corrected that to reflect: `this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'ResetPassword', model, token, email);` and am now getting an error of "Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 4." which is strange as it passes the same 4 arguments as needed

Comment: Post have only two overloads body, httpoptions

Comment: Fixed, thank you Eldho for pushing me in the right direction.  I was unaware of the requirements with Post only having two overloads.  I was able to get this all corrected with a bit of research and using the following change to the service: 

`return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}` + `resetpassword`, {newPassword, confirmPassword, token, email});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue as Eldho pointed out is the Post method can only accept 2 overrides whereas I was sending 4.  It was corrected by changing the authservice method that calls the API to reflect:

```
    resetChangePassword(email: string, token: string, newPassword: any, confirmPassword: any) {
return this.http.post(${this.baseUrl}` + resetpassword, {newPassword, confirmPassword, token, email});
}
```

instead of

```
resetChangePassword(email: string, token: string, model: any) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'ResetPassword' + model + email, token);
  }
```